# Create new pages after 10 lines

Tags: php, html

Here is my php code

```
<?php
$myFile = "hidata.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
    echo ('<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

and here is what in my hidata.txt

```
data1
data2
data3
```

And it echos all lines like this.

```
<li>data1</li>
<li>data2</li>
<li>data3</li>
```

I want my code to create new .php pages after the current page reached more than 10 lines.

As example my .txt file has more than 10 lines of text like this

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
data9
data10
data11
data12
```

And here is what it will echo in the index.php page.

```
<li>data1</li>
<li>data2</li>
<li>data3</li>
<li>data4</li>
<li>data5</li>
<li>data6</li>
<li>data7</li>
<li>data8</li>
<li>data9</li>
<li>data10</li>
```

After 10 lines of texts I want the code to automatically create a new php file `2.php` and the 10 lines or under 10 lines will echo in that `2.php` like this.

```
<li>data11</li>
<li>data12</li>
```

If in my .txt file reaches more than 20 lines then it will create 3.php , if 30 lines then it will create 4.php and so on.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$myFile = "hidata.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$counter = 1;
$page = 2;
while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
    if ( $counter > 10){
         file_put_contents( $page.".php", '<li>' . $theData . '</li>' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND  );
       if ($counter == 20){
               $counter=10;
               $page++;
       }
    }else{
    echo ('<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
   }
   $counter++;
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

So the first run of 10 will be inserted as before in index.php if you execute `php thisscript.php > index.php`

Sure it can be done nicer but I was staying to your initial code.. :)

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine but the problem is it is making the file `2php` not `2.php`. Can you fix it?

Comment: corrected. please also rate it if it according to your need. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a increment/check somewhere in your loop that checks to see if your current file has 10 lines. When that counter reaches 10, start a new file.

```
<?php
$myFile = "hidata.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$count;
while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
    if(count==10)
    {
        //create new file here
    }
    echo ('<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
$count++;
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new php files for every 10 data lines:

```
<?php
    $myFile = "hidata.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $j = 0;
    while(false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))) {
        $i = 0;
        $f = fopen($j.".php", 'w');
        fwrite($f,  '<?php echo("<!--Header of every file.-->"); echo("');
        do {
            fwrite($f, '<li>' . $theData . '</li>');
            $i++;
        } while ($i < 10 && (false !== ($theData = fgets($fh))));
        $j++;
        fwrite($f,  '"); echo("<!--Footer of every file.-->")?>');
        fclose($f);
    }
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

You can further include a `jQuery` function to automatically open created files:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo "$j";?>; i++)
        window.open(i+'.php', '_blank');          
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @Sadie did you include jQuery CDN?